# Android MaterialViewPager issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using material view pager in my application. When I click on any list item then I am going to detail screen and come back then list is overlapped with top Header image. I scroll my material view pager and now I click on the 14th item of the list and it will redirect me to detail screen. Now when I click on back button then list is overlapped with header image. How i can resolve this problem.

[image]

Comment: A picture could explain better and show some relevant code as well

Comment: Image added in the description.